# How to make li in foreach fadeIn and fadeOut on adding and removing, using Custom BindingHandlers?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a foreach binding that shows a list of items from observableArray. I also have functions to add or remove items to that array. I want to make fadeOut and fadeIn on removing/adding. I have already done this by using afterAdd and beforeRemove, but now I have to make it by using custom binding. The fadeIn part isn't a problem, but I can't figure out how to do fadeOut on button click and remove li. Here is my custom binding for fading in:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeIn = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).hide();
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).fadeIn(1000);
    }
};
```

and here is my html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: terms" class="align-center">
    <li data-bind="fadeIn: $data">
        <span data-bind="text: ($data.key + ': ' + $data.value)"></span>
        <span>
            <a data-bind="click: $parent.removeTerm">
                <i class="icon-cancel-circled"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`removeTerm` only removes item from array but I need to make it fadeOut before that. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you make a working jsfiddle?

Comment: It's a part of really big project and I can't. Terms array is being populated by selecting some of search suggestions that I get from server...  I know it would be much easier for you guys... Wish I could...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why create a custom binding, when `click` exists? Just use the click binding and pass your element to your function that wraps fadeOut and remove the element from your list.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: terms" class="align-center">
<li data-bind="click: LaunchFadeOut($data)">test</li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">

var vm = function(){
   this.LaunchFadeOut= function(element){
  $(element).fadeOut(1000);
   // remove element from whatever array
   }
}
</script>
```

EDIT CUSTOM CLICK BINDING

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.customClick = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, viewModel) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
                var click = value.click;
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: function () {
console.log('you were clicked');
                return click.apply(this, array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
            }}, viewModel);
        }
    }

<li data-bind="customClick"></li>
```

I would stress that whomever is getting you to reproduce `click` binding  change their mind. What they are doing is forcing requirements and for you to work against the framework. They are doing this  just because they do not want you to use the built in bindings

Comment: This is a task I was given and I was instructed to do it by using custom bindings. Otherwise I would simply use my solution with afterAdd and beforeRemove. But your suggestion seems fine... if I wasn't supposed to do it like this... Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @MerimaKarić updated my solution for the custom binding that you need to do.

Comment: I have decided to go for the first solution no meter what :) It is clean and simple. But now I have an issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined /I have passed $data as a parameter to fadeOut  method, and if I console log element  it is an object whose key and value I want to fadeOut. But still  $(element).fadeOut(1000); seems to be a problem.

Comment: Found the solution: added beforeRemove: fadeOut and created fadeOut method like this: `self.fadeOut = function(element, index, data) {
          $(element).filter("li").fadeOut(1000);
    };`